# Why can private helper methods still be accessed in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, private, helper

Just another "why is it that way" question: I noticed that private helper methods still can be accessed within views. Why's that? And is there a way to prevent this (e.g. when having helper methods that should only be called from within another helper)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Helpers are [modules that get mixed in](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html#S2) to the views. This means that public, protected and private methods in the helper become public, protected and private methods on the views.

I don't think that you can actually hide the helper methods from the view. You'd need to do something like have a helper class which you instantiate in the helper and then delegate calls to that - sounds like it could get messy fast though. :)